# 'tis the season of new beginnings

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's spring and that means there's a lot of new beginnings out in the world. One of these new beginnings will be a couple of new moderators for this site.

As many of the moderators serving this site before me, I never wanted to keep being a moderator forever. I hoped to be a mostly hidden influence, helping this site and community along the path it was taking. I immensely enjoyed helping the people around here with many a problem in these past two years I had the privilege of serving this community.

For a variety of reasons it seems like my current tenure as a mod has run its course though...
Most of these reasons are personal, but the biggest reason is just straight up burnout from the pandemic.

On one hand I'm sad to leave the ranks of moderators on this site, on the other I'm looking forward to just being the "normal me" again.

For all the help and gracious support I want to especially thank @Simon, @rolfl, @Jamal, @Mathieu and @Malachi.
Another huge thank you goes out to the regulars in the 2nd monitor, the regular flaggers and all the volunteers participating in the moderation process (y'all know who you are).

The powers that be have decided there will be an election starting on April 12th. I look forward to seeing lots of great candidates!

Comment: Thank you for all the great work you've done Vogel! You've always been a great help when I've needed a moderator. I wish you all the best.

Comment: You've put in an enormous amount of work during a time where we needed you. Thank you for your work all these years.

Comment: Thanks for doing great work.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and pointing when my comments for did not match the spirit of the CR or SE policies and rules.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thank you for your service! You have been a pillar in the moderation team since day 1 and it's an absolute honor to have served by your side.

As for myself, as I wrote when I [stepped back up](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9365/23788) in October 2019, I took back the diamond because it made everything simpler for everyone at the time, and now the time has come for me to pass the torch as well.

So, that makes two seats up for grabs - and I'm really looking forward to see who's going to show up!

Comment: Accepting to make sure everyone can also see this :)

Comment: Just when I was about to write "What, we're losing another moderator", I see we're losing 2 at the same time. Carp. I mean, best of luck to the two of you, you've both done plenty for the community, but carp.

Comment: Thanks for doing great work

Comment: Nice way to disappear without drawing too much attention to yourself! Best of luck, ---Mug--- Mathieu!

Answer (score 16):

I've taken a week to stew through what my sentiments are, and how to express them properly.

I believe the best approach is to simply say "thank you". I am fully aware of the burden that being a moderator brings, the way the responsibility weighs on you, disrupts your day, and how sometimes you have to bring objectivity and reason when you're tired or emotional.

I value your contributions to Code Review, I appreciate all the effort, stress, and fatigue that you have encountered as part of that.

You are awesome, @Vogel612 & @Mat's Mug!

That also includes @Jamal, & @Malachai.

Having been in your position as both a moderator (twice), and a departing moderator (twice), I want to try to convey to non-moderators how hard it is to be dedicated behind the scenes, making tough decisions about complex issues, dealing with emotional, angry, or confused users, and at all times of the day. Having to be so careful about every word you say. Every action you take is under intense scrutiny. Having to keep secrets due to privacy concerns. Having to deal objectively and politely with people despite knowing what's happening behind the scenes with them and just wanting to tell them they're jerks ;-) . It can be completely draining, and exhausting.

Of course, there's a lot of positives too, those times when things go right, when people are happy, when the community is growing, and recognition is apparent.

That is what I want to say: Moderators are under appreciated. You're awesome, doing an amazing job, and you should be proud of yourselves.

I hope you have a clear conscience about stepping down. Moderation is not something that you can do forever, you need a break. Also, life changes, things happen, the world is a different place, and your priorities shift. It's not humanly possible to keep at it full time. I learned that when I stepped down the first time, I was done. With a couple of years break, I was able to come back to the job with a more balanced approach to it, but even then, I found that the burden can become excessive, and unhealthy.

So, take a break, relish in being "normal", but don't go too far, we still want you around.

One more thing, no, I will not be running for moderator (this time).

Comment: The only thing I can do is to second the statements given here.

Comment: thank you, I am glad that you are still around also.  Community Moderation is very important to Stack Exchange and the communities that have been built as a result.